# How to read a file system using Spring

Tags: java, spring, directory, subdirectory

What I need: I need a method that, given a specific directory name on my app, will return his content.

```
/root
    /folder1
        /folder11
        /folder12
    /folder2
        /folder21
        /file21.txt
    /folder3
        /file31.txt
        /file32.txt
```

For example, if I call `myMethod("/root");` it will return to me a certain object list containing `{'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'}`. Calling `myMethod("/root/folder2");` will return `{'folder21', 'file21.txt'}`

**Question:** how can I implement this kind of function using Spring?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code that you have so far? It would be great so we can provide some assistance. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just using a Spring Boot rest service, a default one...

Comment: You should post some code and someone will help you to fix it if it's not working - this is  how SO works... Otherwise only thing I can tell you is: read folders recursively.

Comment: Some code would be helpful, but any way: In Java 7

new String(Files.readAllBytes(...)) or Files.readAllLines(...)

In Java 8

Files.lines(..).forEach(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.io.File` if it is a directory you list childs with `docx.list()` and then recursively you can do that for all childs that are directories